# Pass string into a callback function

Tags: angularjs

This is my code:

```
$scope.userDetails = function(userId, type) {
    ajax.get(orginalData.blockData.USER_BASIC_DETAILS + userId, $scope.getUserDetailsCallBack)
}

$scope.getUserDetailsCallBack = function(result) {
    console.log(result)
    $scope.empdetails = result.data.record;         
}
```

Here I need to pass `type` into `callback` method.If I pass like this, am getting `Cannot read property 'record' of undefined` error.

```
$scope.userDetails = function(userId, type) {
    ajax.get(orginalData.blockData.USER_BASIC_DETAILS + userId, $scope.getUserDetailsCallBack(type))
}

$scope.getUserDetailsCallBack = function(result, type) {
    console.log(result,type)
    $scope.empdetails = result.data.record;         
}
```

How to pass it?

Comment: Is `getUserDetailsCallBack` and `getStopDetailsCallBack` same? If yes, you need to update the code. If yes, then my question is, where is `getUserDetailsCallBack` defined?

Comment: Why dont you set type at server side in your response

Comment: @Abhi sorry that is my mistake, both are same methods only check now.

Comment: Then, the answer posted by Alexander should work! :)

Comment: Oops, I didn't see that the functions are different =)

Comment: @AlexanderAnikeev haha no problem .However you gave right answer only ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$scope.userDetails = function(userId, type) {
    ajax.get(orginalData.blockData.USER_BASIC_DETAILS + userId, function (result) {
        $scope.getUserDetailsCallBack(result, type)
    });
}
```